# Howto config embedded Jetty 404 ErrorHandler to customized Spring Controller

Tags: error-handling, embedded-jetty

I have a Spring Controller to handle 404 - the Controller's RequestMapping URI is configured to handle 404 errorCode in web.xml.

I'm using embedded Jetty Server for testing. There's no web.xml file. How can I configure the Jetty server to redirect 404 to my Controller? I've looked at Jetty ErrorHandler, but I'd like to configure and test out my 404 Controller. Is it possible?

Thanks.